# How to manipulate a HTML-Webresource in Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm, office-store, appsource

I have a webresource for Dynamics CRM. The project will be uploaded to the AppSource. It consists of a .html- and a .js-file. If I try to get the elements of the .html-file with document.getElementById in the .js-file, I get the error message, that DOM-Operations are not supported.

How do I manipulate my .html-file with a .js-file?

How do I register a click-event?

I hope you can help me there.

**EDIT**

I just solved the first question:

To access a DOM-Element I needed to use this code:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl(WEBRESOURCE_NAME).getObject().contentDocument.getElementById(id);
```

But how do I register Events on the elements?

**EDIT 2**

I tried to register the events like this:

```
element.ondragenter = function() {...}
```

and like this:

```
element.addEventListener("change", function() {...})
```

Both lines get the same error:

> 'element.onclick = functionName' registers or unregisters handles to a document object model (DOM) event of a model-driven app. This technique is unsupported in all versions of Dynamics 365 and PowerApps and should be replaced with a supported approach for registering client-side event handlers.

**EDIT 3**

I found the solution for the event registration (see my own answer).
Now I have the problem, that I use a FileReader in my .js-script, which uses the onloadend and onerror events. And of course crm does not let me register the events in the file because of the error above.

Comment: maybe [this helps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg334409(v=crm.8)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#BKMK_addOnChange)

Comment: Unfortunally not. This just explains, how I can get every data from the CRM or the entities, but I needed to access elements of the other webresource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to register the events from .html and not from .js.

```
 <div class="DropArea" id="DropArea" ondrop="OnDrop(event)">
```